# invalid read and write valgrind

Tags: c, sockets, valgrind

the following lines are giving invalid read and write error. Can u please explain what i am missing. i have initialized the variable but still it is causing error.

```
==26319==   Invalid read of size 4

==26319==    at 0x4035CC: connection_handler (thread.c:26)

==26319==    by 0x4E36A50: start_thread (in /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so)

==26319==    by 0x61E06FF: ???

==26319==   Address 0x53e02c0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 1 alloc'd

==26319==    at 0x4C27A2E: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:270)

==26319==    by 0x40335C: main (send_server.c:154)


==26319==   1 errors in context 3 of 3:

==26319==   Thread 1:

==26319==   Invalid write of size 4

==26319==    at 0x4033C3: main (send_server.c:157)

==26319==  Address 0x53e02c0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 1 alloc'd

==26319==    at 0x4C27A2E: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:270)

==26319==    by 0x40335C: main (send_server.c:154)
```

Code

```
int *new_sock = NULL;

while (1) 
{
    client_sock = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&client, (socklen_t*)&c); 

    if (client_sock < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"accept failed\n");
        LOGGER("Accept failed\n");
        continue;
    }

    else
    {   
        LOGGER("\nConnection accepted\n");
        pthread_t sniffer_thread;       //assign thread for each client
        if (NULL ==(new_sock = malloc(1))) //invalid read
            continue;       
        printf("VAlue of new sock %p \n",new_sock);
        *new_sock = client_sock; // invalid write of size 4

        if ( pthread_create( &sniffer_thread , NULL ,  connection_handler , (void*) new_sock) < 0)  //Serving each thread
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"could not create thread\n");
            LOGGER("ERROR could not create thread\n");
            free(new_sock);

        }
        pthread_detach(sniffer_thread);
        LOGGER("Handler assigned\n");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using an incorrect argument with `malloc`. You can get the correct size of an int with `sizeof(int)`, which typically yields 4. Try replacing `malloc(1)` with `malloc(sizeof(int))`.

`new_sock = malloc(1)` allocates one byte of memory, and assigns the address of that memory to the variable `new_sock`.

`*new_sock = client_sock;` stores an int into that area of memory; writing four bytes into a one byte area of memory overflows the allocation.

Then, when you try to read an int from that allocated memory (supposedly in another thread), one byte is read from the allocated area, but the other three are being read from invalid memory.

Answer (score 2):

The invalid read isn't shown in the code you posted.

The invalid write is due to the fact that `malloc(3)` takes as argument the space to allocate in bytes.

You are allocating one byte, and point to that byte with an `int *`. So when you dereference your pointer, you are accessing `sizeof(int)` bytes which is bigger than `1` on your platform.

Try using `malloc(sizeof (int))` or even better `malloc(sizeof *new_sock)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
 if (NULL ==(new_sock = malloc(1)))
```

have to be

```
 new_sock = malloc(sizeof(int));
 if(new_sock == NULL)
    continue;
```

[malloc](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_malloc.htm) take a `size_t` parameter that is the **size in bytes** of the amount of memory you want to allocate.
In your case you want to store space for an `int` variable, then `sizeof(int)` returns the right size to alloc.